# text animation in html

Tags: html, css

I have two paragraphs with text in it. i want to animate this text. what i actually want is to move first paragraph from left on x-axis and second paragraph from right to left.

my code is working only for one direction either left or right.

here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

#text {
         position:relative;
         -webkit-animation: mymove infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         animation: mymove infinite;
         animation-duration: 2s;
      }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
         from {top: 200px;}
         to {top: 0px;}
      }

@keyframes mymove {
         from {top: 0px;}
         to {top: 100px;}
      }

#text1 {
         position:relative;
         -webkit-animation: mymove infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         animation: mymove infinite;
         animation-duration: 2s;
       }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
         from {right: -200px;}
         to {right: 0px;}
       }

@keyframes mymove {
         from {top: 0px;}
         to {top: 100px;}
       }

</style>
</head>
<body>
      <p id="text">Some text goes here</p>
      <p id="text1">text display animation</p>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to move second paragraph from right to left and first one from left to right.
what could be the possible solution?

Comment: It is because of duplicate name of 'mymove'. Use some unique id for each animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnsr7Lbq/)

```
#text {
         position:relative;
         -webkit-animation: mymove infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         animation: mymove infinite;
         animation-duration: 2s;
      }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
         from {left: 200px;}
         to {left: 0px;}
      }

@keyframes mymove {
         from {left: 200px;}
         to {left: 0px;}
      }

#text1 {
         position:relative;
         -webkit-animation: mymove1 infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
         animation: mymove1 infinite;
         animation-duration: 2s;
       }

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove1 {
         from {right: 200px;}
         to {right: 0px;}
       }

@keyframes mymove1 {
         from {right: 200px;}
         to {right: 0px;}
       }
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me! what if this should be only one time then it should stop to a particular position. just give me a hint. I'll do it myself. btw thanks!

Comment: #text {
         position:relative;
         -webkit-animation: mymove; 
         -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
         animation: mymove;
         animation-duration: 2s;
      }

Answer (score 1):

inside #text in css add

```
-webkit-animation-direction: reverse; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-direction: reverse;
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/sxscmhy7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxscmhy7/)